# gtk# text editing app put cursor to the beginning of buffer?

Tags: c#, gtk#

In my gtk# text editing app when file opened i.e textview.Buffer.Text,
set to file content, the cursor is placed at the end of buffer while `textview`
view remains scroled on top, could I set somehow cursor to the beginning of buffer? I tried:

```
        Gtk.TextIter iter;
        iter = textview1.Buffer.GetIterAtLine(0);


        textview1.Buffer.Insert(iter, "");
```

But it does nothing :(

Comment: textview1.Buffer.PlaceCursor(iter);

 Did the trick ;)